# Can I execute batch scripts in camunda

Tags: camunda

I have a batch script that is starting java in the end:

**example.bat**

```
call java -jar custom.jar someParameters
```

I wonder how can I execute this in Camunda. Is there a specific task for executing command line tasks. Or do I need to write a groovy script that starts those tasks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right you want to call a Batch-Script from within a Camunda ServiceTask? There is no special support for doing so, so yes, use Java (or Groovy) mechanisms to do so.

if you just want to call Java code you could directly call that from within a ServiceTask, as Camunda is written in Java itself.

Cheers
Bernd